# PHP accept all csv files

Tags: php, csv

I am a PHP beginner writing a program to upload .csv files to a webpage. When testing my program, I have been using a file called Partitions.csv. However, now I need to upload files that are named differently and when I try to do this, my code will not accept the file. This is my HTML code where I upload my file.

```
<form action="uploader.v1.2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".csv"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my PHP code for accepting the file.

```
$sheetData = array();

        if (($handle = fopen($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            while (($dat = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $sheetData[] = $dat;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Error Uploading File")';
            echo '</script>';

        }
```

Could anyone tell me why I cannot upload files that have different file names. Any help would be appreciated. Just to reiterate, I am a PHP beginner

Comment: "now I need to upload files that are named differently", is it just the name of the file that has changed or both name and extension?

Comment: Just the name of the file. I renamed the same file from "Partitions.csv" to "test.csv" for example and my code would not accept the file named "test.csv"

Comment: Turn on error reporting in your php code and see if any errors are generated. Also, check your browser's console and see if any errors or warnings are reported.

Comment: This is the error I get "Warning: fopen(test.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/machacou/public_html/uploader.v1.2.php on line 845"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your upload handler lines with these:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PATH_AND_FINAL_FILENAME)):
if (($handle = fopen(YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PATH_AND_FINAL_FILENAME, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($dat = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $sheetData[] = $dat;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error Uploading File")';
        echo '</script>';

    }
endif;
```

Where "YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PATH_AND_FINAL_FILENAME" represents a directory path and filename on your server: e.g: "/wamp/www/uploads/test.csv".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, there's no reason why a file with a different name wouldn't work. Most likely it is the CSV format that is slightly different.

In fact, parsing CSV can be very complex especially if you need to support "all csv files". So rather than use the built-in PHP functions, which can be quite limited, I'd suggest using a specialized package such as this one:

https://github.com/thephpleague/csv

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will try to use this package

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the attribute `accept` must contains MIME type:

> text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, text/anytext, application/csv,
>   application/excel, application/vnd.msexce, application/vnd.ms-excel

Secondly, CSV is a text format and file extension may be differ than .csv.
But if you want to filter by extension, you can do it on clien-side using FileAPI (https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/).